# C++ Cant Change Object's Variables

Tags: class, object

```
class ship {
public:
    int location;
    int length;
};

void createship(ship ship1, int gridsize) {             //function to set ship1's length and location
    srand(time(NULL));
    ship1.length = (int)((rand()) % gridsize) / 4 + 1;
    ship1.location = (int)(rand()) % gridsize;
}

void insertship(ship ship1, vector <char> grid) {           //insert ship into grid, change grid's elements from 'e' to 'f'
    for (int temp2= 0; temp2 < ship1.length; temp2++) {
        grid[ship1.location + temp2] = 'f';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int gridsize;
    cout << "Gridsize: ";
    cin >> gridsize;
    cout << "\n";
    vector <char> grid(gridsize, 'e');
    for (int temp3 = 0; temp3 < grid.size(); temp3++) {         //cout vector grid
        cout << grid[temp3];
    }
    cout << "\n";
    ship* ship1 = new ship();                               //create ship1
    createship(*ship1, gridsize);
    insertship(*ship1, grid);
    cout << (*ship1).length << "\n";
    cout << (*ship1).location << "\n";
    for (int temp4 = 0; temp4 < grid.size(); temp4++) {         //cout vector grid again (with ship)
        cout << grid[temp4];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My ship1.length and ship1.location always remain as zero, even though the createship() function is supposed to change it to a random figure? Is there any mistake I made?

Just to add more words below because stackexchange doesn't allow me to add mostly code in my question

Comment: You need to pass by reference, otherwise you're only modifying the local `createship::ship1` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were passing a parameter by value which will create and change a local variable in the function instead of the source variable.
You should pass the parameter by reference.

```
void createship(ship &ship1, int gridsize) {            
  srand(time(NULL));
  ship1.length = (int)((rand()) % gridsize) / 4 + 1;
  ship1.location = (int)(rand()) % gridsize;
}
```

Anyway,in you case, using a member function maybe a better solution.

```
class ship {
public:
  int location;
  int length;
  void createship(int gridsize) { 
    srand(time(NULL));
    this->length = (int)((rand()) % gridsize) / 4 + 1;
    this->location = (int)(rand()) % gridsize;
  }
};
```

call：

```
ship1->createship(100);
```

Comment: Thank you! I did the same for insertship() too, but it didn't work though (the 2nd cout still prints all 'e'). Is there a reason why?

Comment: did you pass the vector as reference?

Answer (score 0):

You pass the `ship` by value, so the parameter `createship` gets is a copy of the original object and changing it won't change the original.

Pass a reference/pointer to `ship` and then changes to the parameter will change the original object.

Or much better, use a [constructor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm).